# Webpage Hml Plain Text in C# winforms

Tags: c#, html, winforms

i am working on c# winforms.I have textbox in which user put url.First i got all html source of url webpage then i tried to get its plain text after removing all html tags
i used this method.

```
private string StripHTML(string source)
        {
            try
            {
                string result;
                result = source.Replace("\r", " ");
                result = result.Replace("\n", " ");
                result = result.Replace("\t", string.Empty);
                result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                                                                      @"( )+", " ");
                result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                         @"<( )*head([^>])*>", "<head>",
                         System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                         @"(<( )*(/)( )*head( )*>)", "</head>",
                         System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                         "(<head>).*(</head>)", string.Empty,
                         System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                         @"<( )*script([^>])*>", "<script>",
                         System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                         @"(<( )*(/)( )*script( )*>)", "</script>",
                         System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                         @"(<script>).*(</script>)", string.Empty,
                         System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                         @"<( )*style([^>])*>", "<style>",
                         System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                         @"(<( )*(/)( )*style( )*>)", "</style>",
                         System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                         "(<style>).*(</style>)", string.Empty,
                         System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                         @"<( )*td([^>])*>", "\t",
                         System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                         @"<( )*br( )*>", "\r",
                         System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                         @"<( )*li( )*>", "\r",
                         System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                         @"<( )*div([^>])*>", "\r\r",
                         System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                         @"<( )*tr([^>])*>", "\r\r",
                         System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                         @"<( )*p([^>])*>", "\r\r",
                         System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                         @"<[^>]*>", string.Empty,
                         System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                         @" ", " ",
                         System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                         @"&bull;", " * ",
                         System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                         @"&lsaquo;", "<",
                         System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                         @"&rsaquo;", ">",
                         System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                         @"&trade;", "(tm)",
                         System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                         @"&frasl;", "/",
                         System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                         @"&lt;", "<",
                         System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                         @"&gt;", ">",
                         System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                         @"&copy;", "(c)",
                         System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                         @"&reg;", "(r)",
                         System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                         @"&(.{2,6});", string.Empty,
                         System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                result = result.Replace("\n", "\r");
                result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                         "(\r)( )+(\r)", "\r\r",
                         System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                         "(\t)( )+(\t)", "\t\t",
                         System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                         "(\t)( )+(\r)", "\t\r",
                         System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                         "(\r)( )+(\t)", "\r\t",
                         System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                         "(\r)(\t)+(\r)", "\r\r",
                         System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                         "(\r)(\t)+", "\r\t",
                         System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                string breaks = "\r\r\r";
                string tabs = "\t\t\t\t\t";
                for (int index = 0; index < result.Length; index++)
                {
                    result = result.Replace(breaks, "\r\r");
                    result = result.Replace(tabs, "\t\t\t\t");
                    breaks = breaks + "\r";
                    tabs = tabs + "\t";
                }
                return result;
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error");
                return source;
            }
        }
```

But this is not working in most situation.
Can any body tell me proper solution.
I tried this method too.

```
public string getContent(string webAddress)
    {
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(webAddress);

            style.Remove();
        return string.Join(" ", doc.DocumentNode.Descendants().Select(x => x.InnerText));
    }
```

it works with all pages except some.
but at some places it shows like

```
<div class="overlay"></div> <div id="no-js-block" class="row"> <div class="large-12 columns"> <p class="like-h1 margin-top-1">
```

also this like

```
<iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-MX6MFP" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe>
```

Comment: Can any body tell me another method of fetching the plain text from html source of page.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: There are quite a few alternatives to parse HTML code (do some research); using `Regex` is not one of them.

Comment: where is the solution it isn't there it is a article about regex is not proper solution that i am already saying.